# Are there published testimonies from individuals who had a Christophany in which Jesus explicitly affirmed or denied his deity?

Tags: resource-request, extra-biblical, divinity, testimony, christophany

Christophanies (a.k.a. encounters with Jesus) are supernatural experiences which are entirely within the realm of possibility according to Scripture. Three clear examples are Paul's ([Acts 9:3-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+9%3A3-6&version=ESV)), Ananias's ([Acts 9:10-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+9%3A10-16&version=ESV)) and Stephen's ([Acts 7:54-56](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts+7%3A54-56&version=ESV)). In light of this, I was wondering if there are any published extra-biblical testimonies about Christophanies, in which Jesus explicitly stated his divine status. Has anyone ever published a testimony of their encounter with Christ, in which Jesus explicitly affirmed or denied his deity?

Comment: I haven't looked deeper into it, but the Wikipedia entry for Christophany mentions a few such testimonies. Could be a starting point to see what, if anything, was said about Jesus' divine status.

Comment: You might start with [Julian of Norwich](https://www.bl.uk/collection-items/the-short-text-of-julian-of-norwichs-revelations-of-divine-love#)

Comment: Perhaps you should change your subject from 'from Christians who' to 'from people who', since your answer includes 2 people who were not Christians at the time of their christophanies?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather - excellent point. Question edited as suggested. Technically they are Christians now though, but at the exact moment of their encounters they were not. Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Members of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe that God called Joseph Smith as a prophet in modern times, [restored](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/media/video/2018-10-0030-the-restoration-now-you-know?lang=eng) the fullness of the Gospel of Jesus Christ through him, and that God the Father and Jesus Christ appeared to him on multiple occasions as part of this process.

I'll cite two specific examples of revelations Joseph Smith indicated he received from God, which have direct bearing on the OP's question.

**1. December 7, 1830 - Fayette, New York:**

As recorded in Doctrine & Covenants 35:

> 1 Listen to the voice of **the Lord your God**, even **Alpha and Omega**, the
> beginning and the end, whose course is one eternal round, the same
> today as yesterday, and forever.
>
> 2 I am **Jesus Christ**, the **Son of God**, who was crucified for the sins of
> the world, even as many as will believe on my name, that they may
> become the sons of God, even one in me as I am one in the Father, as
> the Father is one in me, that we may be one.

Here the speaker identifies Himself by several titles, including God, Alpha and Omega, Jesus Christ, and the Son of God.

**2. April 3, 1836 - Kirtland, Ohio:**

As recorded in Doctrine & Covenants 110:

> 2 We saw the Lord standing upon the breastwork of the pulpit, before
> us; and under his feet was a paved work of pure gold, in color like
> amber.
>
> 3 His eyes were as a flame of fire; the hair of his head was white
> like the pure snow; his countenance shone above the brightness of the
> sun; and his voice was as the sound of the rushing of great waters,
> even the voice of **Jehovah**, saying:
>
> 4 I am **the first and the last**; I am he who liveth, I am **he who was
> slain**; I am your advocate with the Father.

(Note on the "we" in this passage - this vision was beheld by Joseph Smith and Oliver Cowdery)

Here Jehovah is identified as the first and the last and the one who was slain. Note the comparable language to that found in Revelation chapter 1.

--

More than a dozen comparable examples could be cited, many of which are found in the [Doctrine & Covenants](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/title-page?lang=eng).

---

Disambiguation:

- Latter-day Saints believe that Jesus was known pre-mortally as Jehovah, and that He is a separate Being from God the Father.
- We believe in the Deity of God the Father and we believe in the Deity of His Son, Jesus Christ. Those who wish to discuss the implications for monotheism may find it fruitful to ask a separate question.

---

Disclaimer: my comments are the product of my own study and do not constitute official statements by The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints

Answer (score 3):

After spending some time searching, I found two testimonies from ex-Muslims who had life-changing christophanies. Let their testimonies speak for themselves:

- [A former Iranian hezbollah member shares about his encounter with Jesus Christ](https://youtu.be/hQgCGFemNNQ?t=687).

> [...] So, how is it ... who is this God that says "I forgive you"? And I feel forgiven today. And I asked him *'Who are you, that you forgive me and I feel forgiven today?'*. **And he says *'I am the way, the truth and the life'***. The moment I heard those words I knew it was of great importance, but I had absolutely no idea what that meant. I still had no clue who this God is. So I asked him *'What is your name?'*. ***'Jesus Christ, the living God*' he answered** [...]

- [Muslim Jihadist Accepted ''Jesus is God'' testimony amazing](https://youtu.be/RFR4wH_cgvE?t=347)

> [...] Now I fell on my knees and I put my hands to the heavens immediately as I heard the voice, and I cried out with every fiber within me: ***'God, the Father of Abraham! If you are real, would you speak to me?! God, the Father of Abraham! If you are real, I want to know you!'*** Well, God, the Father of Abraham came to the room and he filled the room with his glory, and his name was Yahweh, the Lord is one, **and in his hands, he has holes in his hands, he has holes in his feet, his name is Jesus**. I said to him *'Who are you, my lord? Who are you?'* He said *'I am that I am'*. I said *'I'm a simple man, with a simple mind. What's that supposed to mean?'* He said *'I'm the alpha, I'm the omega, I'm the beginning, I'm the end, I'm everything that is in between. I have known you before I form the foundation of the earth. I have loved you before I formed you in your mother's womb. Rise up, rise up, come on. You are my warrior, you are not their warrior'*. I said to him *'my lord, my lord, I will live and die for you'*. He said ***'Do not die for me. I died for you that you may live'*** [...]