# How common are apparitions of Mary and/or other Saints amongst non-Catholics?

Tags: virgin-mary, saint, non-christians, communion-of-saints, apparitions

How common are apparitions of Mary and/or other Saints amongst non-Catholics? There are many testimonies about these sorts of apparitions published on the web, but people who report these experiences typically had some connection with the Catholic faith prior to the apparition. But what about non-Catholics? What about Protestant Christians? What about Jews, Muslims, Buddhists, Hindus, atheists, etc.? For the purposes of comparison, stories of dreams, visions and encounters with Jesus among Muslims are [not](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83548/50422) [uncommon](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/79535/50422), but what about Mary and other Saints who passed away?

Comment: I again object to the phrase **”deceased Saints among non-Catholics”** We view the saints as **living** although dead in the flesh, they are  spiritually  full of life!!! Mary is very well alive in heaven!  Encounters with Jesus, the Prophet, amongst Muslims remain uncommon!

Comment: @KenGraham - if you have a better terminology in mind, feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How common are apparitions of Mary and/or others Saints among non-Catholics?**

They are not very common, but nevertheless they do happen. At least in the eyes of the Catholic Church. They are not so much publicized because of their end result: Non-Catholic seers are expected to conver to the Catholic Church before being recognized as a valid Catholic apparition before Catholic authorities will decreed it worthy of belief.

Protestants do not want to favour Catholic or Orthodox spirituality or teachings. Nevertheless such apparitions do occur.

> Indeed. 52 years ago, the Virgin Mary appears several times in the district of Zeitoun in Cairo!
>
> On the night of April 2 to 3, 1968, a Muslim garage owner goes out for a cigarette. He crouches down against the entrance of his garage, takes his lighter, lights his cigarette of the brand "Cleopatra" and... drops it immediately!
>
> A woman, all dressed in white, bright and radiant, stands on the roof of the small Coptic Orthodox church in the neighborhood that stand on the opposite side of his garage. She is on the edge of the void!
>
> The mechanic runs towards the church to warn the caretaker and try to reason this woman who must be thinking of jumping and committing suicide.
>
> But that's not the case...
>
> He stares closer, rubs his eyes: a golden halo and scarlet light overlooks this woman, she does not walk but flies slightly over the roof of the church.
>
> The Muslim mechanic falls to his knees: he has just recognized "Maryam".
>
> The mother of Jesus, "Issa" among Muslims... He prays and opens his hands to heaven and already some people run up and recognize an apparition: "Ya Maryam! "exclaimed the first Christians who saw the apparition.
>
> The Virgin Mary is there, present, radiant and luminous, in this poor and working-class district of Cairo.
>
> For three years, the apparitions followed one another at random intervals: a few hours, minutes spaced by days, weeks or months. They will be recognized by the Coptic Orthodox Church, the Catholic Church and the great Sunni Mosque and religious institution of Al Azhar.
>
> [image: The Miracle of Zeitoun]
>
> [**Egypt: The Miracle of Zeitoun, 1968: The Virgin Mary appears to the Egyptians**](https://www.soschretiensdorient.fr/index.php/en/item/1506-egypte-le-miracle-de-zeitoun-1968-la-vierge-marie-apparait-aux-egyptiens).

Our Lady appeared to a Protestant (former Catholic) **Bruno Cornacchiola** in Rome on April 12, 1947. He ended up reconverting to the Catholic Church.

> “You Persecute Me…Enough of It Now! Enter Into the True Fold, God’s Kingdom on Earth.”
>
> April 12, 1947
>
> It was a sunny Saturday after Easter in 1947. Bruno Cornacchiola, a railway worker, decided to take his three children— Isola, aged 10, Carlo, aged 7, and Gianfranco, aged 4—on a picnic. That afternoon he providentially missed a train going to Ostia and decided to go to the parkline Tre Fontane shrine area instead.
>
> It was also, alas, notorious as a place of sin in which even the bodies of dead preborn babies were found. There, in the shade of the eucalyptus, while his children played, Bruno pored over his Bible. He was preparing a speech which he intended to deliver in a public square the following day, attacking the Church’s teaching on the Immaculate Conception.
>
> Although Bruno had been baptized a Catholic and received his First Holy Communion, he did not practice his Faith. A few months after he was married, he deserted his wife and volunteered to fight in the Spanish Civil War. It was there that he embraced Protestantism, eventually becoming a militant Seventh Day Adventist. In 1939 he returned to Rome and to his wife, who remained a practicing Catholic. Prone to uncontrollable rages, he often beat her up. He forbade church attendance for the children and refused to have the youngest son baptized.
>
> Besides being a wife-beater, Bruno Cornacchiola’s language was punctuated frequently with obscenities and blasphemy, and he had affairs with other women. The very morning of the picnic he passed a statue of Our Lady which read on its base, “Virgin Mother.” Bruno wrote in pencil, “You are neither virgin nor mother.”
>
> In his great hatred of the Church, he was even devising a plot to assassinate Pope Pius XII on September 8, the feast of the birthday of the Blessed Virgin Mary. But on the afternoon of April 12, in the middle of his preparation for his verbal attack on Mary’s great prerogative, one of his children interrupted him. Would he help them find their ball?
>
> Bruno put aside his notes and joined in the search, only to find his youngest son, Gianfranco, kneeling at the entrance to a dark cave.The boy’s hands were folded in the attitude of prayer, as though in ecstasy, and he repeated, “Beautiful lady! Beautiful lady!” as though he were addressing a living person.
>
> Bruno was surprised, then uneasy, and finally seized by terror. He could see nothing in the cave; what was he to make of his son’s strange behavior?
>
> Excitedly he turned to Isola and Carlo for an explanation. Initially curious and fearful, within seconds they also—first Isola and thenCarlo—fell to their knees and joined their hands in prayer, enraptured with the same vision. Bruno was dumbfounded. Then he heard all three of his children cry out together: “Beautiful lady!” He tried to move each child, but they were as if glued to the ground. He was terrified.
>
> Suddenly, Bruno was also overcome by the strange mystical experience. His eyes were filled with intense light for a moment, then everything disappeared: his children and the cave. He felt himself becoming weightless, ethereal, as if his spirit had been freed of his body. When he regained his sight, Bruno saw in the cave a woman of indescribable beauty, and clothed in radiant white. Her black hair was surrounded by a halo of brilliant golden light. Her dress was gathered by a rose-colored sash, and over her shoulders she wore a striking green mantle....- [The Virgin of Revelation at Tre Fontane (Three Fountains)](https://insidethevatican.com/magazine/the-virgin-of-revelation-at-tre-fontane-three-fountains/)